# Formatting Objects using AngularJS dynamic number

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to format objects using this [library](https://github.com/uhlryk/angular-dynamic-number). It doesn't support objects, I get objects, they are numbers but objects not int, I want to put a comma as a thousand separator. I asked the author, he didn't reply yet.

I have to add a strategy, anyone tried it before? Is there any other library capable of doing that? I'm using AngularJS 1.x

Comment: Can you show some code to clarify what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the creator of the library and he said

> Yes. please check
> http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/uhlryk/angular-dynamic-number/blob/master/examples/index.html
>
> and at the bottom there are section "Example of angular dynamic number
> filter" It begins from this line
> https://github.com/uhlryk/angular-dynamic-number/blob/master/examples/index.html#L159

I guess this answers my question